# Database schema migration

Tags: mysql

Before I reinvent the wheel is there a simple tool out there that does schema migration similar to laravel but using standard SQL?

Many schema migration tools just apply migration files based on the numeric prefix where said prefix is greater than the current table increment.

I'm more interested in a tool that loops through all the files in a migration directory in order (numeric prefix) and applies any MISSING (from the databases migration table) sql migration files to the database.

Prefer FOSS and wouldn't kick rollback functionality out of bed either.

Answer (score 2):

[Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) seems like a perfect fit - it works on plain SQL files in the migrations directory and uses a DB table to keep track of the migrations that were already applied to the target DB.

Comment: I saw that but was really only investigating FOSS solutions.  I edited to clarify in my original post.

Comment: Flyway is an Open Source project (although there are commercial versions, as well), so it should still fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it meets all of your needs, but at work we control our database schema with [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). I'm not the DBA here, so from a dev standpoint, it's pretty simple. We just create a yaml file with our SQL and do regular commits, PR's, etc in the git repo. So it's intuitive on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Both tools [FlywayDB](https://flywaydb.org) and [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/index.html) are perfect to handle database migration. 
Both tools a licensed under the 'Apache 2.0 License'. So you have the possibilty to contribute and the source code is public hosted on Github.

FlywayDB are more version number orienented and store the migration in a table. Numeric prefix as you requested.

Liquibase works with changesets and the order depends on the changeset order in the changelog file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to a very simple alternative (but still powerful) take a look at [dbmate](https://github.com/amacneil/dbmate)

Comment: I actually did check out dbmate. It didn't really meet my needs.  I might check it out again though as it has been quite a long time since I checked it out.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Looks like exactly what I wanted.  This project needs better SEO  :) flyway and liquibase dominate search results.

Answer (score 1):

Besides flyway and liquibase, there is a new one [Bytebase](https://bytebase.com), which has nice GUI and support GitOps.

Answer (score 0):

Not a generic answer though if you are into PHP you should consider doctrine-migrations: https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/migrations

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GitHub/GitLab like equivalence for schema migration, then check out [Bytebase](https://www.bytebase.com).